Graph of electric potential with distance problem
Consider this graph for the variation of $x$ of the total electric potential $V$ due to two spheres. There are two separate spheres, and we are looking at the variation of electric potential as we move from the centre of one sphere to the centre of the other.

The problem asks for some qualitative or quantitative conclusions about the two spheres. Firstly the answers say we can determine the radius of the spheres as $0.3$ and $0.1$ respectively. This makes sense considering the electric potential inside a sphere is constant and the electric field strength is zero. However, I have reservations about this. Won't the charge of the other sphere still have an influence when inside the other sphere? So, why is the electric potential constant? Is this a simplification to assume the charge on the other sphere is negligible?
Secondly, the answers state the charges on the sphere are the same. This doesn't make complete sense to me. If the charges were the same, wouldn't there be a region in between both charges where the electric potential is zero? However, the graph only has non-zero values so I don't quite understand this. So, how are we able to make this claim that the charges are the same, both numerically and sign?
Could someone please explain how the shape of this graph comes about? Are there simplifications being made as stated above for this graph? If the charges are the same why is the graph not symmetrical? Why does the graph go down and then up again? I am looking for a detailed explanation of the shaped of this graph.

The spheres must be conductors, i.e. copper spheres. We can know that because the electric field inside a conductor is zero. Your statement about the influence of the other sphere charge makes sense, and it would be the case if the spheres where made of any other material rather than a conductor.
Electric Field inside the conductor is zero because charges can move freely inside the conductor (that is why we call them conductor) so charge will organize themselves to minimize energy. The Electric energy goes with the modulus of the electric field, so the minimum possible value is zero. So the reason why spheres don't create fields in each other is because they own charges reorganize to screen the other sphere effects.
For your second question, the condition if the spheres have the same total charge is that the electric field is 0 in the middle, not the potential. And you can observe that in the graphic, the derivative of the potential is 0 at 0.6 so the field is zero.
You can think in electric potential as high of a hill. If a ball is on the top of the hill, it doesn't have any force acting on it, but if the ball move a little to the right or to the left, the ball will fall all down the hill. The same situation here, a positive charge in the middle of two spheres have not net force (because there is no field), but if it would be move a little up or down, the electric force will send the charge to the infinity.

awesome, this answered everything
